# How to get arguments?

Tags: c#

What is the reason I am not getting args[] through command? And how should I fix it to get the args passed in

[image]

I used this code:

```
namespace Kautohelper_OpenDevtool
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string title = "";
            //string title = "Privacy error - Hidemium";
            if (args.Length > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" length ->    ", args.Length);
                for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
                {
                    string title_cm = args[i].Split('=')[0];
                    Console.WriteLine(">>>>>>>>   ", title_cm);
                    
                    if (title_cm == "--title_input=")
                    {
                        title = args[i].Split('=')[1];
                        Console.WriteLine("====>   ", title);
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("---->   ",title);

         }
    }
}
```

Comment: first try to log all elements from args ... remeber this is array ... if you wana string then you must join its elements with a spaces

Comment: also after split  char/string which was splitted on is not in the result ... so obviously comparing to "--title_input=" doesnt make sens ... also there is `System.CommandLine` ...

Comment: "question2answer". You have read the description of that tag?

Comment: I tried :
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("---> ",args);
        }

but it doesn't get any value at all

Comment: [do not upload images of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: You are using `WriteLine()` incorrectly. Try `Console.WriteLine($" length ->    {args.Length}")` or `Console.WriteLine(" length ->    {0}", args.Length)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters passed to **Console.WriteLine()** are incorrect. If you call it with two or more parameters, the first is a string containing placeholders, like this:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("length -> {0}", args.Length);
```

Or just use one parameter like this:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("length -> " + args.Length.ToString());
```

Or use string interpolation (note the `$` before the first `"`):

```cs
Console.WriteLine($"length -> {args.Length}");
```